# Why does NSArrayController fetches twice in a row?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I encountered some weird behavior in my OS X app that uses Core Data and NSArrayController. Each fetch: message sent to the array controller results in a *double fetch* from the persistence store (sqlite), taking twice the time to do the fetch, of course.

It happens when I set the fetchPredicate property of the array controller and then send a fetch: message.

I created a simple test app using the standard apple Core Data app template with one entity 'SomeEntity' with just one attribute 'stringAttribute'. I subclassed NSArrayController and overrode fetchWithRequest:merge:error: to set a breakpoint and see whenever array controller fetches from the store.

Then, I wrote a simple action method (wired to a push button) containing only two lines:

```
self.arrayController.fetchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
[self.arrayController fetch:self];
```

And again, each time I pressed the button the fetchWithRequest:merge:error: method was called twice, resulting in two trips to the persistence store.

NSArrayController inherits from NSObjectController who implements the fetch: method. The docs say that

> Beginning with OS X v10.4 the result of this method is deferred until the next iteration of the runloop so that the error presentation mechanism can provide feedback as a sheet.

fetchWithRequest:merge:error: is indeed called by an NSInvocation triggered in the run loop mechanism. After a little breakpoint setting I found out that one NSInvocation is created by the line

```
self.arrayController.fetchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
```

and a second one by the next line

```
[self.arrayController fetch:self];
```

When I comment-out the second line, the controller doesn't fetch at all. So as long as I want to set the fetch predicate prior to fetching I get two fetches. Strangely, this doesn't happen when I press my button *for the first time after app launch.*

This feels weird because I basically only added two lines of code to the standard Core Data stack. When I fill the store with test data and measure the time fetchWithRequest:merge:error: takes to complete, I can clearly see the performance problem of the fetch happening twice and taking twice the time.

Directly calling fetchWithRequest:merge:error: wouldn't be an ideal solution because there are some automagical features in NSArrayController that I would have to reimplement myself. And shouldn't it be the right way to first set fetchPredicate and than simply call fetch:?

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Is arrayController.automaticallyPreparesContent switched on?

Comment: No it's not, but interesting question. When I switch it on, it fetches twice right after XIB load! So we see fetchWithRequest:merge:error: called twice (and taking twice the time) even if we don't write any code at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `NSArrayController` tries to be smart and automagically fetches in `setFetchPredicate:` if it has fetched before.

Comment: No it doesn't fetch when I set the predicate. That's what makes it so weird. It doesn't fetch unless I call fetch:. It fetches either twice or not at all.

Comment: You have to call `fetch:` at least once or switch `automaticallyPreparesContent` on. If `NSArrayController` has never fetched it doesn't fetch in `setFetchPredicate:`. If `NSArrayController` has fetched before calling `setFetchPredicate:` it does fetch in `setFetchPredicate:`.

Comment: Ah thanks, now I understand what's going on. But I must say it would be nice if NSArrayController would be even smarter and avoid enqueueing these double fetches on the run loop.